# Recurring image function in canvas fails after one call

Tags: javascript, image, canvas

I'm trying to build an interactive blackjack table with chips and play buttons. Instead of drawing the chips individually, I wanted to draw a circle, put the image of the chip inside, and crop the rest of the picture.

```js
function getMousePos(canvas, event) {
    let button = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
    return {
        x: event.clientX - button.left,
        y: event.clientY - button.top
    };
}

function isInside (pos, button) {
    return pos.x > button.x && pos.x < button.x+button.width && pos.y < button.y+button.height && pos.y > button.y
}


function draw() {
    const canvas = document.getElementById('bjGame');
    const width = canvas.width = window.innerWidth-40;
    const height = canvas.height = window.innerHeight-40;
    if (canvas.getContext) {
        const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
        let chip1 = new Image();
        let chip5 = new Image();

        //Background
        ctx.fillStyle = "rgba(29,129,36,0.71)";
        ctx.fillRect(0, 0, width, height);

        //This works-
        createChip(ctx, chip1, 300, 300, "images/chip1.png");

        //But once I add this line of code it completely breaks
        createChip(ctx, chip5, 100, 100, "images/chip5.png")


    }
}

function createChip(ctx, chip, x, y, imgSrc) {
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(x, y);
    ctx.arc(x, y, 40, 0, 2*Math.PI);
    ctx.clip();

    chip.addEventListener('load', ()=> {
        ctx.drawImage(chip, 30, 11, 100, 100, x-40, y-40, 80, 80);
    }, false);

    chip.src = imgSrc;
}
```

I've been trying to avoid making the same lines of code for the 8 different required chips but the function has a one-time-use for some reason.

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vyjg8pdu/)

Comment: Also, load your assets (images) first, then start your drawing logic. Here the `ctx.drawImage` call in the onload function will happen way after you define everything else (so if you fix the clipping issue you have, it will be drawn outside of the clipped region).

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/d516utL7/

Comment: Oh this is super helpful!!! Thank you!!!!